# Finding the longest palindrome in a string using recursion

Tags: java, string, algorithm, palindrome

I am stuck on why my solution only works for some strings. For example, "sdfbananabasdf" would return "bananab", but "dtattarrattatddetartrateedre" would run in an infinite loop. Thank you in advance!

```
public String longestPalindrome(String s) {
    if(isPalindrome(s)) {
        return s;
    }
    String divisionOne = longestPalindrome(s.substring(0,s.length()-1));
    String divisionTwo = longestPalindrome(s.substring(1,s.length()));
    return (divisionOne.length() >= divisionTwo.length()) ? divisionOne : divisionTwo;        
}

private boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    if(s.length() == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    int count = s.length() / 2;

    if(s.length() % 2 == 1) {
        count++;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(s.length() - 1 - i)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: How do you know that it is infinite loop? What is the time complexity of your algo?

Comment: I know your question specifies recursion but you might be interested in a non-recursive algorithm that finds the longest palindromic substring in linear time: [Manacher's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring)

Comment: First find an input as small as possible, where your algorithm fails. Second use a debugger or any kind of debug-output to compare step by step what your algorithm does with what you expected it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the time complexity of your algo is `O(2^n)`

Let say `f(n)` is the function to calculate the palindrome for string with length `n`, in the worst case, we can see that

```
f(n) = 2*f(n - 1)
f(n - 1) = 2*f(n - 2)
...
f(1) = 1
```

-> `f(n)` time complexity is `O(2^n)`

So, for long string, your program will take long time to run. Like in the example, a string with 29 character will require O(2^29) or O(5*10^8) operations.

**Note**: Actually, each operation requires two additional `substring` and a `isPalindrome` operations, which will make the time complexity is O(n*2^n), not just O(2^n)

How to reduce the time complexity? Dynamic programming should be the answer

Comment: @GhostCat For his example, there are 29 characters, which is 2^29 ~ 5*10^8, but let me take another look :)

Comment: Thank you @PhamTrung ! I've realized it is a time complexity issue